# Passing pointers to new operator

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management

What this code means? As per this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) there is no way to pass pointer to the new operator. the `new` operator here is default one, not an overloaded one. please help

```
LPVOID m_Buffer;
MyClass* mc = new(reinterpret_cast<void*>(m_Buffer)) MyClass;
```

Comment: Here be dragons. You don't want to use it.

Comment: Your quoted code is very dangerous, as it's trying to do placement new with an uninitialised address. This means that you'll be performing construction of `MyClass` into a random, potentially unallocated address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html). It is used to e.g. place objects at an specified location.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, what the `reinterpret_cast` does here?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is not unchecked (as are all C++-style casts). The compiler verifies that the type being casted from and the type being casted to are compatible with each other. If they are not, the compile fails.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but it's unchecked at run-time. That's what I've meant, sorry.

Comment: This just casts the LPVOID to void*. There is a difference between those two, e.g. compare Difference between LPVOID and void*. reinterpret_cast is not checked at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html). This version of new operator allows you to place new instances in pre-allocated memory. It is quite useful when you want to allocate a lot instances, because you'll drastically reduce count of actual memory operations, which may increase performance of your application.

Example (taken from Parashift C++ FAQ):

```
#include <new>        // Must #include this to use "placement new"
#include "Fred.h"     // Declaration of class Fred

void someCode()
{
    char memory[sizeof(Fred)];     // Line #1
    void* place = memory;          // Line #2

    Fred* f = new(place) Fred();   // Line #3 (see "DANGER" below)
    // The pointers f and place will be equal

    ...
}
```

It is worth noting though, that you have to know *exactly* how much space a class needs and that may vary due to compiler settings/platform and a dozen other reasons. So use it *only* if you need it and when you *really* know what you're doing.

Comment: You don't need to assign `memory` to a separate `void*` variable before passing it to `new()`. You can pass `memory` directly to `new()`, as all pointers implicitly degrade to `void*`: `Fred* f = new(memory) Fred();`